# Error on short pointer in C

Tags: c

I'm getting an error on the second while loop "invalid pointer operation" i thinking its because of the len but i need it to be a pointer so i can address this back. Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

```
char* getWord(char* string, short* len)
{
 size_t walker = 0;

  /*POINT TO THE FIRST CHAR*/
  while (string[walker] == ' ' || string[walker] == '\0')
   ++walker;


 while ( string[walker + len] != ' ' || string[walker + len] != '\0'  )
   ++len;

 return (string[walker]);
```

Comment: Why is `len` a pointer? Make it a non-pointer, or say `*len`!

Comment: @Kerrek SB - he wants it to be an out parameter...

Comment: Hey, isn't this really dangerous? If you pass an empty string `""`  to the first while loop, it'll just move right past the valid memory.

Comment: ... and is `*len` intentionally not being initialized? I mean, do you want to pass an existing value in to start the tokenization at a non-zero offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deference it:

```
while ( string[walker + *len] != ' ' || string[walker + *len] != '\0'  )
     ++(*len);
```

but first make sure it is initialized...

Also, you need to return the pointer to the word, not the char at this address, so write:

```
return (&string[walker]);
```

instead of

```
return (string[walker]);
```

Answer (score 3):

The illegal pointer operation is the addition of `walker` and `len`.

Basically, you're adding a `size_t` and a `short *`. Maybe you need to dereference `len` first:

```
string[walker + *len]
```

Or, `len` wasn't supposed to be a pointer in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Should `len` be a pointer? If yes, then change `string[walker + len]` to `string[walker + *len]`.